# apt updates time out before completed

Tags: apt, updates, ipv6

When I run "sudo apt-get update", it hangs on a line like this:

```
0% [Connecting to archive.canonical.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b)]
[Connecting to dl.google.com (2607:f8b0:400d:c0a::5d)]
```

Nothing happens. Looks like IPv6 is used, but that should be working? Any idea what is wrong? This has started happening a week ago or so.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu release?

Comment: archives? that probably means an old version. please disable that source/repository.

Comment: What is the output of `ip addr` and `ip -6 route`?

Answer (score 0):

Disable ipv6.  You can do this by:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Append this:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Run this command:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Details at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsingSlowIPv6IPv4