# apt-get error couldn't connect to ubuntu archive

Tags: apt, 16.04, repository

I can't update or install app from repository because of `apt-get` error. For example, when I try to run `sudo apt-get update`, the process stuck at `0% [Connecting to az.archive.ubuntu.com (94.20.20.125)]` and couldn't continue after this line. Then it returns an error with the explanation:

```
Could not connect to az.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (94.20.20.125), connection timed out.
```

The same thing happens, when I run sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser. Please, help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Disable ipv6.  Look at: http://askubuntu.com/a/823758/29012

Comment: I already tried that solution. It didn't work.

Comment: What is the output of `test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo "Running kernel is IPv6 ready`?

Comment: output of  "test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo" is nothing

Comment: That's a confirmation that it's something else.

Comment: I'm sorry. I ran a wrong command. The output is "Running kernel is IPv6 ready".

Comment: What do you get when you run this?  1 or 0? `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`

Comment: it returned "e_ipv6

Comment: it returned "e_ipv6 1"

Comment: The content should only be a single character `1`.  I'm sure if you used `less` rather than `cat` to check the content, it would be 1.  But anyway, that's a verification that it's something else.  IPv6 is indeed disabled.

Comment: @Elgin Cahangirov  What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 lts